# Office 365 API - Get meeting room location and capacity

Tags: office365api

I'm doing an integration of mobile app with the Office 365 Calendar. I want to show room capacity and location on the screen. I trying to find an API to get meeting room info (this info is available on website when selecting room as user).

I tried both [Outlook REST API (version 2.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api) and  [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) but found nothing in the docs on how to get such info.

Where I can find such API if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but you can do it using the List Places API in Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room

RESPONSE:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#places/microsoft.graph.room",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "3162F1E1-C4C0-604B-51D8-91DA78989EB1",
      "emailAddress": "cf100@contoso.com",
      "displayName": "Conf Room 100",
      "address": {
        "street": "4567 Main Street",
        "city": "Buffalo",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "98052",
        "countryOrRegion": "USA"
      },
      "geoCoordinates": {
        "latitude": 47.640568390488626,
        "longitude": -122.1293731033803
      },
      "phone": "000-000-0000",
      "nickname": "Conf Room",
      "label": "100",
      "capacity": 50,
      "building": "1",
      "floorNumber": 1,
      "isManaged": true,
      "isWheelChairAccessible": false,
      "bookingType": "standard",
      "tags": [
        "bean bags"
      ],
      "audioDeviceName": null,
      "videoDeviceName": null,
      "displayDevice": "surface hub"
    },
    {
      "id": "3162F1E1-C4C0-604B-51D8-91DA78970B97",
      "emailAddress": "cf200@contoso.com",
      "displayName": "Conf Room 200",
      "address": {
        "street": "4567 Main Street",
        "city": "Buffalo",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "98052",
        "countryOrRegion": "USA"
      },
      "geoCoordinates": {
        "latitude": 47.640568390488625,
        "longitude": -122.1293731033802
      },
      "phone": "000-000-0000",
      "nickname": "Conf Room",
      "label": "200",
      "capacity": 40,
      "building": "2",
      "floorNumber": 2,
      "isManaged": true,
      "isWheelChairAccessible": false,
      "bookingType": "standard",
      "tags": [
        "benches",
        "nice view"
      ],
      "audioDeviceName": null,
      "videoDeviceName": null,
      "displayDevice": "surface hub"
    }
  ]
}
```